# Reporting services knowing how a colour will appear in excel export

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have been playing around with some reports and exporting them to excel, only to find that the colour in SSRS is not even remotely close to that in excel - for example if I have a textbox that is PaleGreen is SSRS, it comes out a rather unpleasant shade of grey.

Is there a way of knowing which SSRS colours will look the same in excel exports so I can stick to those? I'm using SSRS 2005 and excel 2003 (but can use Excel 2007 if it helps).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this is caused by the algorithm that is used to match the reporting services colors up to the excel color pallet. There is no fix for this. I usually tend to try to use basic colors Silver, White, Blue, etc. to avoid these issues.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sqlreportingservices/thread/c592e7ac-84a4-4dc1-9c82-bd1657e7a9b4

Comment: Thanks for this - it's what I'd expected deep down, shame really!

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be excel 2003 limited palete problem.

A workaround could be:

Open excel 2003, choose a color and check it's RGB values, and convert them to HEX

In reporting services use the HEX value as background color.

You can find an online DEC to HEX converter here:
http://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-decimal-hexadecimal-converter.html

Comment: I think that although this is a good workaround, I really want to be able to set the colours from SSRS rather than defining them from excel as this will go on to be exported in multiple formats - thanks for the link though :)

Comment: I think there is no other way since reporting services use the old xls format. As far as I know, only the new version of SQL server will support the xlsx format.

Comment: Guess this is (yet) anothe reason to upgrade to SSRS 2008 then :)

Comment: Denali is the version in which the new format will be officially supported, so you will have to wait a little longer :) I think tablix and how the newer version's handle memory and export (have you ever tried to export a "heavy" report) is the main reason to upgrade